# GCP Cloud Scheduler retry_count not respected

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

I'm having an issue running a cron using the GCP's Cloud Scheduler. The target type is HTTP. Retry config is set as follows (and visible in attached screenshot):

- max retry attempts (`retry_count`) = 0
- max retry duration = 1h
- min backoff duration = 5s
- max backoff duration = 1h
- max doublings = 5
- attempt deadline = 30m

However, no matter what value is set as the "max retry attempts" (0-5), whenever the called endpoint returns `500`, the call is then retried 5 times. It seems as if the setting for retry count didn't have any effect. I want to see 0 retries when the request fails. What would you suggest?

The called endpoint is running on Cloud Run. The request takes approx. 1 minute to complete.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is an intended behavior ,`retryCount` will work along with [`maxRetryDuration`](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.locations.jobs#:%7E:text=attempted.%20If%20specified-,with%20retryCount,-%2C%20the%20job%20will). This means that, in order to avoid having the job retry, you have to set `minBackoffDuration` larger than `maxRetryDuration` while Keeping `retryCount` at 0.

For example:

```
minBackoffDuration=5s
maxRetryDuration=1s
```

When having these settings, if a job fails, the job should not be retried since the next run time will be in `minBackoffDuration=5s` which is larger than `maxRetryDuration=1s`.

Comment: Thank you for your response! How can this be intended, though? Why would I be able to set a parameter `retryCount` ("Max retry attempts") if it doesn't actually alter the count of the retries . Does the `retryCount` actually do something?

Comment: Anyway, I set the `maxRetryDuration` to `1s` (while keeping `retryCount` at `0` and `minBackoffDuration` at `5s`, but I still got one retry. (It is not the five retries anymore at least.)

Comment: @JameStitel I have given just examples, As you said request take 1min to complete. Can you try to set  `maxRetryDuration = 60s` and `minBackoffDuration` to greater than `60s`?

Comment: I set the `maxRetryDuration` to `60s` and then tried various values of `minBackoffDuration` greater than `60s`, however, there is always one retry "`minBackoffDuration` seconds" after the first attempt fails.

Comment: @JameStitel I followed this [qwiklab](https://www.cloudskillsboost.google/focuses/3556?parent=catalog) and deleted `pub/sub` topic to make request fail. I tried following configurations  `maxRetryDuration = 5m`, `minBackoffDuration=10m`, `maxBackoffDuration = 1h`, `maxDoublings = 1` and i didn't get any retries. And can you tell what is the value you have given to [`frequency`](https://cloud.google.com/scheduler/docs/configuring/cron-job-schedules)